# asp.net listview in updatepanel shifted column after refreshing

Tags: asp.net, listview, updatepanel

Whenever I tried to add/delete/update row on the listview, it will add another invisible column to the third column of row 6.  However, if I press F5, it will back to normal. I have already studied the source but found no problem so far(no extra 'td' added before the shited column/>  I tried in on Firefox and Chrome and no abnormality found there.  I do see Chrome 'fix' it in front of my own eyes.

So did I miss anything important?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: must see your markup to say anything about this. also your insert and display methods

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem only appear in IE 9 through development tool, I used this information and googled it.  Turns out all I need is removing space between 'tr' and 'td'.  That fixed the problem!